# Find how many items open for certain month in sql server with 2 date columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a sample view with some dates. How would you find the number of items opened per months. Say between the time they were open and closed OpenDate and CloseDate I want to find how many were open for each month January, February, etc. ?

October Had 4 items opened.

Here is a sample table with the data

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestDate](
    [ItemTitle] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ItemAttachAssignDate] [date] NULL,
    [ItemDetachConcludeDate] [date] NULL,
    [Status] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [FullName] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [OpenDate] [date] NULL,
    [CloseDate] [date] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO


INSERT INTO [TestDate]([ItemAttachAssignDate], [ItemDetachConcludeDate], [Status], [FullName], [OpenDate], [CloseDate]) 
    VALUES('2013-02-18 00:00:00', '2013-02-19 00:00:00', 'Done', 'Jeff Hunter      ', '2013-02-18 00:00:00', '2013-02-19 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO [TestDate]([ItemAttachAssignDate], [ItemDetachConcludeDate], [Status], [FullName], [OpenDate], [CloseDate]) 
    VALUES('2012-10-15 00:00:00', '2013-02-05 00:00:00', 'Done', 'Tommy Johnson', '2013-01-22 00:00:00', '2013-01-28 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO [TestDate]([ItemAttachAssignDate], [ItemDetachConcludeDate], [Status], [FullName], [OpenDate], [CloseDate]) 
    VALUES('2012-10-15 00:00:00', '2013-02-05 00:00:00', 'Done', 'Jeff Haynes', '2012-10-17 00:00:00', '2013-02-01 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO [TestDate]([ItemAttachAssignDate], [ItemDetachConcludeDate], [Status], [FullName], [OpenDate], [CloseDate]) 
    VALUES('2012-10-15 00:00:00', '2013-02-05 00:00:00', 'Done', 'Nancy Belkin', '2012-10-28 00:00:00', '2012-12-14 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO [TestDate]([ItemAttachAssignDate], [ItemDetachConcludeDate], [Status], [FullName], [OpenDate], [CloseDate]) 
    VALUES('2012-10-15 00:00:00', '2013-02-05 00:00:00', 'Done', 'Rudolph Porche', '2013-01-16 00:00:00', '2013-02-02 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO [TestDate]([ItemAttachAssignDate], [ItemDetachConcludeDate], [Status], [FullName], [OpenDate], [CloseDate]) 
    VALUES('2012-10-20 00:00:00', '2013-02-07 00:00:00', 'Done', 'Pat Franks', '2013-01-20 00:00:00', '2013-01-25 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO [TestDate]([ItemAttachAssignDate], [ItemDetachConcludeDate], [Status], [FullName], [OpenDate], [CloseDate]) 
    VALUES('2012-10-20 00:00:00', '2013-02-07 00:00:00', 'Done', 'Leslie Jordan', '2012-11-25 00:00:00', '2012-12-04 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO [TestDate]([ItemAttachAssignDate], [ItemDetachConcludeDate], [Status], [FullName], [OpenDate], [CloseDate]) 
    VALUES('2012-10-20 00:00:00', '2013-02-07 00:00:00', 'Done', 'Fred Haney', '2012-10-20 00:00:00', '2013-02-04 00:00:00');

INSERT INTO [TestDate]([ItemAttachAssignDate], [ItemDetachConcludeDate], [Status], [FullName], [OpenDate], [CloseDate]) 
    VALUES('2012-10-20 00:00:00', '2013-02-07 00:00:00', 'Done', 'Henry Hanks', '2012-10-31 00:00:00', '2012-11-15 00:00:00');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand this part of your question:

> Say between OpenDate and CloseDate

Does that mean you need to do some sort of date calculation or comparison?

But if you're just looking for monthly aggregates, there's a few ways of handling this. You could have a Date reference or dimension table that you join to, which contains a mapping of days-to-months. Or you could simply strip the pertinent parts of the date, i.e.

```
SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, OpenDate) AS OpenYear
    , DATEPART(MONTH, OpenDate) AS OpenMonth
    , COUNT(*) AS OpenCount
FROM dbo.TestDate
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, OpenDate)
    , DATEPART(MONTH, OpenDate);
```

You could also roll up the counts to the first day of the month, i.e.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,OpenDate),0),120) AS OpenMonth
    , COUNT(*) AS OpenCount
FROM dbo.TestDate
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,OpenDate),0),120);
```

It just depends on what you're doing with the data and how you need it presented. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you really want to find out is "for each month, the number of items actively in open status". For example, one item's opendate is Nov. 15th 2012, closedate is Jan. 2nd, 2013, you are considering this item open for 3 month, and each month, the open item count should be +1 because this item.

If so, the following script will help you. It is straightforward logic, it must have better neat code to replace this one

```
select YearMonth, SUM(OpenItemCount)
from (
select cast(DATEPART(YYYY,CloseDate) as varchar(4)) + CAST(DATEPART(mm,CloseDate) as varchar(2)) as YearMonth, 
       COUNT(*) as OpenItemCount 
from  [dbo].[TestDate]
group by cast(DATEPART(YYYY,CloseDate) as varchar(4)) + CAST(DATEPART(mm,CloseDate) as varchar(2))    
union all    
select cast(DATEPART(YYYY,OpenDate) as varchar(4)) + CAST(DATEPART(mm,OpenDate) as varchar(2)) as YearMonth, 
       COUNT(*) as OpenItemCount 
from  [dbo].[TestDate]
where (cast(DATEPART(YYYY,OpenDate) as varchar(4)) + CAST(DATEPART(mm,OpenDate) as varchar(2))) <> (cast(DATEPART(YYYY,CloseDate) as varchar(4)) + CAST(DATEPART(mm,CloseDate) as varchar(2)))
group by cast(DATEPART(YYYY,OpenDate) as varchar(4)) + CAST(DATEPART(mm,OpenDate) as varchar(2))    
) as A
group by A.YearMonth
```

Comment: Basically what I'm doing is, first aggregate basing on CloseDate, then aggregate basing on Opendate, when I aggregate basing on opendate, I exclude the case open and close in the same month.

Comment: Convert to varchar is because I want to show year and month. I don't want to aggregate same month from different year.

Answer (score 0):

Option with master..spt_values system table and [APPLY()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) operator.FYI, COUNT() of month calculate on all years

```
SELECT DATENAME(mm, DATEADD(mm, number-1, '20010101')) AS month, o.cnt
FROM master..spt_values v CROSS APPLY (
                                       SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt
                                       FROM [dbo].[TestDate]
                                       WHERE v.number = MONTH(OpenDate)
                                       ) o                                       
WHERE v.type = 'P' AND v.number BETWEEN 1 AND 12
```

Comment: That's a nice neat solution. +1